# Python using cgi to fill into html template while template don't know how many will be inserted

Tags: python, html, cgi

First, I have a html template like

```
<p> The first element in list is %s </p>
<p> The second element in list is %s </p>
.......
```

If I know there are only two elements from cgi script, I can use template % mylist to fill the template.
But when I don't know how many elements will be generated from cgi script, I don't know how many %s to put in template, then I cannot fill the template properly.

Any idea to generate the template based on result from cgi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, usually you should not use cgi but rather wsgi (e.g. with flask).

then, if you have a modern template language (like jinja2) there are usually loop constructions, so you can iterate over as many list elements as there are.